# Why couldn't Gandalf kill multiple orcs at a time?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, gandalf

We see Gandalf fight and defeat the Balrog. He loses his own life in the process, but through this battle we learn that at the very least he is as at least as powerful, if not more powerful, than the Balrog.

Fast forward to *The Return of the King* and the armies of Sauron are attacking Gondor. We see hordes of orcs rushing in off of their siege towers and Gandalf fighting them off with his sword and staff, but doing so one at a time. I can't help but think of the Balrog at this point... If the Balrog were entering Gondor, or defending it for that matter (although that would never happen) it would be smiting everything in its path dozens at a time. Although we never actually see the Balrog fighting anything save for Gandalf I think it is pretty safe to assume it would be incredibly formidable against whatever were in front of it, even a dozen trolls or more.

So if Gandalf is more powerful than the Balrog, why couldn't he do the same to the orcs as he did to the Balrog? Why is he fighting one orc at a time with his sword and staff instead of decimating dozens at a time with some form of magic, be it his ring, his staff or any other form of power he may possess?

As far as crowd control goes, Legolas, Gimli and Aragorn are actually shown as much more of a threat to Sauron's army than Gandalf is. All Gandalf really ever did was shine a flashlight a couple times, other than that it was just one-at-a-time swordfighting.

Comment: Do we see him fighting more than one balrog at a time?

Comment: How does one fight more than one at a time with one weapon? Is he just going to swing his sword and knock down 4 with one swing?

Comment: Gandalf was not sent to be a war machine, slaugthering orcs and uruks in his way, but to lead, support and aid. Also fighting the Balrog was NOT easy. He died. Fighting multiple targets at once is also not easy and could easily result in a stab in the back (hopefully there will be a hobbit somewhere behind you to protect you.)

Comment: What in the world does fighting more than 1 belrog at a time have to do with only fighting 1 orc at a time? What 1 belrog is equal to 1 orc, is that your point?

Comment: "How does one fight more than one at a time with one weapon?" I guess you missed the scene at the beginning of the fellowship where the witch king is plowing threw multiple humans using....1 weapon! My point wasn't that Gandalf was just fighting 1 orc at a time, my point was that if he is supposed to be this all powerful wizard he wasn't very all powerful.

Comment: He is NOT supposed to be an "all powerful wizard".  Gandalf and the other wizards were specifically ordered to restrain their power and to inspire and lead rather than fighting like.  The Balrog was an exception, where he had no choice and most of the fighting was done after they dropped were out of sight anyone.

Comment: suchiuomizu - That is an answer that I can accept. I was reading pretty much the same thing not long before you replied. My thinking was... if he had the power why didn't he use it? And of course the answer is like you said, that he was not supposed to, and being very by the book he didn't(except for out of sight with the belrog).

Comment: I agree with Mix.  Gandalf wasn't sent to be a major combatant.  In fact if I remember correctly he was specifically forbidden from matching power for power with Sauron.  Gandalf's job was to rally mankind, advise and support them..

Comment: Also, (and this is more speculative so I didn't put it in the answer) while it's not explained mechanistically - Tolkien didn't generally write like that - in my view Gandalf was able to fight the Balrog because his own nature as a Maia kept him from being quickly killed by the Balrog's "magical" powers like its fiery aura/presence. But against a large number of mortal opponents, the Balrog's fire and big demon body would mean it would do far better than Gandalf (who can fry orcs and wolves, sure, but he has to actively DO something - he's not just radiating fire all the time).

Comment: Not a bad question imo, even if loosely so. Don't feel like searching for references on this (and going mainly by opinion), but I think that we should keep in mind that Gandalf and the Balrog are both Maia. So if there is a restriction on Gandalf involving himself too much in battle against normal creatures, the restriction may not exist in case of fighting creatures like himself. Against orcs, he's just a skilled warrior - but, against a fellow Maia, all bets are off.

Comment: It should also be noted that every single person who has taken down a Balrog (two more examples: Glorfindel and Ecthelion) also went down with it. And Gandalf actually was allowed to do what he did with the Balrog; Tolkien made this very clear and it's exactly why he was returned and made Gandalf the White: because he saved the Company at his expense.

Answer (score 6):

Under the right circumstances, Gandalf could kill multiple orcs at once; he's done it in the past:

> But not Gandalf. Bilbo's yell had done that much good. It had wakened him up wide in a splintered second, and when goblins came to grab him, there was a terrific flash like lightning in the cave, a smell like gunpowder, and several of them fell dead.
>
> *The Hobbit ch. IV: Over Hill and Under Hill*

However, Gandalf's essential task as a wizard (one of the Istari) is to inspire and advise the Free Peoples in fighting Sauron, not to do the primary fighting himself:

> But they [the Istari] were forbidden to match his [Sauron's] power with power
>
> *LOTR, Appendix B*

Also, there's a difference between killing a small group of orcs and a large organized army.

Gandalf's ability to defeat a Balrog at the cost of his own life doesn't mean that he would be as effective against a horde of orcs as a Balrog would be.

As one of the Istari, Gandalf's body is fundamentally human in nature (though either ageless or incredibly long-lived). Saruman was killed by an ordinary Man (Grima) with a knife. Gandalf's status as a Maia wouldn't necessarily protect him from being swarmed and killed by a large group of orcs.

Comment: One could argue though that since the Balrogs were from Melko/Melkor/Morgoth he in fact wasn't doing anything wrt Sauron. It's not as simple as that but it's an interesting thing (at least for me) to think about. Even so though he had to do what he did and it doesn't take away the value of your answer - I just thought I'd throw in that philosophical question too.